# Row blocks in Hive (how to group rows by certain criteria and count these groups)

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Here is a sample of the data I have:

```
Date_key       UserID
20140401         a
20140402         a
20140406         a
20140407         a 
20140408         a
20140409         a
20140404         b
20140408         b
20140409         b
20140414         b
20140415         b
...              ...
```

Each row has a Date, User ID couple which indicates that that user was active on that day. A user can appear on multiple dates and a date will have multiple users -- just like in the example.

I want to get the number of consecutive day groups (i.e. blocks of activity). For example, this value for *'User a'* would be **2** because they were active on 20140401 and 20140402 which is the first group of consecutive days. After 20140402, they waited for a while before becoming active again (i.e. they were not active the following day). On 20140406, their second block of activity started and continued without any break up until 20140409. For *'User b'*, this value would be **3** because they have been active during three consecutive day periods: 1)20140404 2) 20140408, 20140409 3) 20140414, 20140415

I use Hive. I am not sure if this is possible in Hive, but if the data needs to be carried over to a RDBMS to perform this task, I can do that too. Your recommendations are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

When you use the distribute by clause, ie: .......distribute by user_id sort by user_id,date_key desc...... all the records for a particular user would go to a particular reducer, where the records are then sorted by date_key descending. Here why don't we write a UDF to iterate through the records, and when ever there is break in the continuity it would increment the counter for continuity by 1 and return the result along with the user_id.